# Scatter plot points do not resemble data and appear very off-scale

Tags: python, pandas, matplotlib, seaborn, scatter-plot

I have a data set of about 300 points, each with a corresponding X value and Y value. There is also a third column in the data with a "Quality" label, either saying "Good" or "Bad", and so there are three columns of data in my data frame, 2 are numeric, and one is string.

I simply want to make a scatter plot of these data points, with the "Good" points in blue and the "Bad" points in red, with a legend showing me this color distinction. Yet I am just not able to match in python the plot I was able to make in Excel.

In Excel, I simply made a scatter plot of the X and Y columns and got this, which looks correct to me:
[image]

I then try to create this plot in python using the following code:

```
x = df['X']
y = df['Y']

plt.scatter(x, y)
plt.show()
```

And I get this mess of a plot which is confusing me:
[image]

Beyond the axis tick marks looking horribly crammed together, the data points are not making any sense to me at all, they do not at all resemble the Excel plot I made, which is using the exact same data. Maybe this could be an axis formatting issue, but I do not know.

How can I fix my code to properly capture the data points shown in my Excel plot?

Comment: What does the data look like?

Comment: The Excel plot I posted is what the data looks like, just plotting both columns. Is there another way I should show this?

Comment: As in we can't reproduce your plot, find the error in your code and/or fix it without the data

Comment: The easiest option is `ax = sns.scatterplot(data=df, x='X', y='Y', hue='Quality')`. Also your data is currently being plotted as strings, not numeric.

Comment: @TrentonMcKinney yup that was the issue I was able to resolve, it was strings, so I made it float, and the data then looked correct. Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming you have read your data into a pandas dataframe with `df = pd.read_csv("/path/to/your/file")`, and it has three columns as: `X`, `Y`, and `Quality`, the following should do the trick for you:

```
# Separate the data into two groups based on the 'Quality' column
good_data = df[df['Quality'] == 'Good']
bad_data = df[df['Quality'] == 'Bad']

# Create a scatter plot
plt.scatter(good_data['X'], good_data['Y'], color='blue', label='Good')
plt.scatter(bad_data['X'], bad_data['Y'], color='red', label='Bad')

# Adding labels and title (optional)
plt.xlabel('X')
plt.ylabel('Y')
plt.title('Scatter Plot of Good vs Bad Quality Data')

# Show the legend
plt.legend()

# Show the plot
plt.show()
```